# How to paginate a sql table without cutting on a certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine this sample table data ordered by country name:

```
CustomerID  Country
12          Argentina
54          Argentina
20          Austria
59          Austria
50          Belgium
76          Belgium
77          Belgium
15          Brazil
21          Brazil
31          Brazil
34          Brazil
88          Brazil
10          Canada
42          Canada
51          Canada
73          Denmark
74          France
84          France
85          France
1           Germany
6           Germany
17          Germany
37          Ireland
27          Italy
49          Italy
66          Italy
2           Mexico
3           Mexico
```

How could I paginate it by a limit of no more than 10(has exceptions) with out it returning pages that cut in the middle of country groups. Here is the expected result

**variable with page = 1 returns**

```
12          Argentina
54          Argentina
20          Austria
59          Austria
50          Belgium
76          Belgium
77          Belgium
```

**variable with page = 2 returns**

```
15          Brazil
21          Brazil
31          Brazil
34          Brazil
88          Brazil
10          Canada
42          Canada
51          Canada
73          Denmark
```

**variable with page = 3 returns**

```
74          France
84          France
85          France
1           Germany
6           Germany
17          Germany
37          Ireland
```

**variable with page = 4 returns**

```
27          Italy
49          Italy
66          Italy
2           Mexico
3           Mexico
```

An exception to the limit of 10 is if there are more than 10 rows with the same country.

I tried a couple things with limit and offset but still haven't found any clean/simple query. I am doing this for chunking purposes. Any help is much appreciated. You can play around with the data [HERE!](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_desc)

Comment: I think this requires a recursive CTE, which is only available in MySQL 8+.

Comment: Hey guys. I can't place a bounty yet but if someone finds an answer for this I will make one and then award it later

Comment: What version of MySQL? What have you tried, specifically? What is your definition of "clean/simple query"? What are your performance constraints? How big is this data set? You absolutely cannot do this in application code?

Comment: I could do it in application code but thought doing it in sql directly might be more efficient. We're talking something like 30,000 rows. I have another way that can load n countries worth of rows but then the calls are returning differently sized chunks and I was hoping to distribute them out better. Using ```mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23```

Comment: I am almost certain this will perform better in app code than MySQL -- it requires memory (retention of state, not capacity to hold fact) as it goes along, and memory isn't something the declarative nature of SQL provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in MySQL using variables.  This is quite challenging because you need to keep track of the page and the row number within the page.  But, MySQL only really supports one expression per variable.  More specifically, it doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

The logic is then to add a new column for the page, which you can use for pagination.  The logic is something like this:

```
select t.*,
       @p := (case when @c = country
                   then (case when @rn = 10  -- a county has more than 10 rows
                              then (case when (@rn := 1) = null then null -- never happens
                                         else (@p := @p + 1) 
                                    end)
                              else (case when (@rn := @rn + 1) = null then null -- never happens
                                         else @p
                                    end)
                         end)
                    when (@rn + cnt > 10)  -- start a new page
                    then (case when (@rn := 1) = null then null -- never happens
                               else (@p := @p + 1)
                          end)
                    else (case when (@rn := @rn + 1) = null then null -- never happens
                               else @p
                          end)
             end) as page
from (select t.*, c.cnt
      from t join
           (select country, count(*) as cnt
            from t
            group by country
           ) c
           on t.country = c.country
      order by t.country, t.CustomerID
    ) t cross join
    (select @rn := 0, @p := 0, @c := '') params
order by page, t.country, t.CustomerId;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=21a054c2502af263ea044ed6f6d8fbde) is a db<>fiddle that shows the code working (in at least some cases).

Comment: What's the performance profile given the SQL uses a CROSS JOIN and the OP has 30k rows?

Comment: @bishop . . . The `CROSS JOIN` has nothing to do with performance.  A `CROSS JOIN` to a single row is pretty much a no-op performance-wise.  This requires some sorting of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I did not look at the detail, just saw two subqueries cross joined and alarm bells went off.

Comment: I'll revisit this sometime soon and compare the speeds of the queries. For now I just went to test it but wasn't able to get the query to run because it was erroring out on the else statement. Will keep you posted once I get back to this. Thanks so much! I'm sure I'll get it figured out soon. Will accept the answer once I'm certain it works.

Comment: @Max . . . I'm not surprised the code didn't work without testing.  I wanted to demonstrate that variables could work instead of recursive CTEs.  I fixed the code and provided a working example.